# Extracting Numbers from String RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am really struggling with Regular Expressions and can't seem to extract the number from this string

```
"id":143331539043251,
```

I've tried with this ... but I'm getting compilation errors

```
var regex = new Regex(@""id:"\d+,");
```

Note that the full string contains other numbers I don't want. I want numbers between id: and the ending ,

Comment: Where did this string come from? It looks like it could potentially be part of a piece of [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json), in which case you should use a proper JSON parser, and not regex.

Comment: It did, but the server returns malformed JSON, that contains JSON within JSON. I had complicating issues with it, which is why I decided to use a regular expression.

Comment: JSON is allowed to contain JSON so long as it's property quoted; you just need to parse the inner piece(s) a second time.

Comment: @MattBall that's the issue, it isn't properly formatted. I've had headaches with it. It's not really an issue using RegEx as I only need one bit of data from the JSON, which is the ID's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need is the digits, just match on that:

```
[0-9]+
```

Note that I am not using `\d` as that would match on *any* digit (such as Arabic numerals) in the .NET regex engine.

---

Update, following comments on the question and on this answer - the following regex will match the pattern and place the matched numbers in a capturing group:

```
@"""id"":([0-9]+),"
```

Used as:

```
Regex.Match(@"""id"":143331539043251,", @"""id"":([0-9]+),").Groups[1].Value
```

Which returns `143331539043251`.

Comment: Yes but the entire string contains other number that I don't want. I need it grab numbers between id: and the ending ,

Comment: @JamesJeffery - That's a fairly important detail. Something you would want to mention in the question. Why not edit it and do just that?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\""id\"":(?<num>\d+)");
var yourNumber = match.Groups["num"].Value;
```

Then use extracted number `yourNumber` as a string or parse it to number type.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using LINQ try the following (c#):

string stringVariable = "123cccccbb---556876---==";

var f = (from a in stringVariable.ToCharArray() where Char.IsDigit(a) == true select a);

var number = String.Join("", f);